# Reading string data from file

Tags: java, json, file

I want to read string data from file and has to pass each strings in the file for some operation.For ex if my file possess links of a website then I have to extract each link and parse its data.I have already done parsing for sites by passing URL as input.But now I think its favorable to store entire links as string and pass it as argument.So how can I read URL from a file and parse each URL data?Can any one specify the code for doing this?

Comment: have you already tried something?

Comment: You don't understand what?

Comment: `Can any one specify the code for doing this?`: Note that StackOverflow will **help** you with your code, not **write** it.

Comment: File file = new File("myfil"); try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) { int content; while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) { // convert to char and display it System.out.print((char) content); }......I tried this.But I want the url in string format

Comment: Suppose I have all list of links in myfil.txt then how should I convert it into string..Iam new to java especially to files

Comment: Try [Googling this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=reading+file+to+a+string+java&oq=reading+file+to+a+string+java&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.7572j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was your code that I read from your comment:

```
File file = new File("myfil"); 
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) { 
    int content; while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) { // convert to char and display it
    System.out.print((char) content); }
```

This is that mess fixed up:

```
File file = new File("myfil"); 
String fileContent = ""; // String to keep track of file content
try { 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    int content; 

    while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) 
    {
        fileContent += (char)content; // append this to the file content as char
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print("Problem reading file");
}

System.out.print(fileContent); // print it
```

Keep in mind, you will have to import some stuff into your project. These are the import lines, if you don't already have them:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your file contains a url on each line do this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with line.
}
```

But you should be more specific in your question. Where is the problem?

Comment: File file = new File("myfil");
      
  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
 
   
 
   int content;
   while ((content = fis.read()) != -1)
   {
    // convert to char and display it
    System.out.print((char) content);
    
    
   }......I tried this.But I want the url in string format

Comment: well this is not what I suggested. do what I posted and you will have a string

Comment: did you even read the answer?

Comment: my mistake..now it's working..actually I was asking about my code snippet

Comment: Lol "did you even read the answer" +1

Comment: @chopz your code snippet? You put "your code" in a comment. If you want people to help you with your code, put it in your question. You can `edit` it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wan't to write code at all, just use the [FileUtils-class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...

public void yourMethod() {
  List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(yourFile);
}
```

Comment: That's neat. Can you also include the import statement into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for get list with all url's of your file and later iterate list for do something.

This is a sample example.

```
public class GetURL {

public static void extractUrls(String input, List<URL> allUrls)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("\\b(((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~\\/|\\/)|www.)"
                    + "(\\w+:\\w+@)?(([-\\w]+\\.)+(com|org|net|gov"
                    + "|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum"
                    + "|travel|[a-z]{2}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?"
                    + "(((\\/([-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|\\/)+|\\?|#)?"
                    + "((\\?([-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?"
                    + "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)"
                    + "(&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?"
                    + "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*"
                    + "(#([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?\\b");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        allUrls.add(new URL(matcher.group()));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<URL> allUrls = new ArrayList<URL>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./urls.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {            
        extractUrls(line, allUrls);
    }

    Iterator<URL> it = allUrls.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
                    //Do something
        System.out.println(it.next().toString());
    }

}

}
```

Take a look at Apache Commons FileUtils and method readFileToString(File source) for convert directly file to String.